# Obtain primes with threads. How to divide intervals?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

I want to obtain all the prime numbers in the interval `[min, max]`. I want to do the calculus in `n` servers. Which is the best way to divide my initial interval in another `n` intervals, to manage approximately the same load in all the `n` servers?

---

[Optional]

---

I had an idea, but it didnt work as I expected. I assumed that all numbers are primes, so that a number `i` costs `i` instructions to verify is a prime.

If we keep in mind this method:

"https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/f/6/3f627df07a1cca70507dc0562f564f32.png"

Then, the number of instructions to get primes in interval [1,100] is `1+2+..+99+100 = 100(1+100)/2 = 5050`.

Now, if I want to do this calculus in 2 servers (`n=2`), I have to divide this load to each one (2525 instructions each one). The interval I want is defined by `2525 = x(1+x)/2 -> x=71`.

In general terms, the general formula would be `Load = (Interval(x) - Interval(x-1) + 1) * (Interval(x-1) + Interval(x)) / 2`, being `Load = (max - min + 1) * (min + max) / (2 * n)`.

Doing this, with `x and y = [1:9999999]` and `n = 16`, I have got this results:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_948211012c6a4f9423d5b03819d.png

I dont get the same time and instructions in all servers, what means this is not the way to divide the intervals.

Any idea?

*(I couldn't post images, not enough reputation).*

Comment: I'm not sure how you get 5050, do you mean that to check if e.g. 5 is prime you divide it by 5(?!),4,3,2,1(?!) to get 5 operations?

Comment: Yes, true. But I've realised I only need to check from 2 to sqrt(n)+1. I did it in code but not in calculus.

Comment: Are you counting down in your loop and breaking out of the loop once you find a divisor?

Comment: Yes I'm doing. My code is correct, only that the interval calculus is incorrect. I count primes to sqrt(n)+1 in my code and to n in the interval calculus. When i get this error solved I will test the results and get you informed.

Comment: I don't think your interval analysis is going to have any bearing on your results if it doesn't model your code, which it doesn't. If you are interested in understanding why your analysis is wrong, breaking in the loops is why. If you are interested in computing primes quickly, only check known primes $\leq \sqrt{N}$.

Comment: I suggest you look into the relative speeds of sieves compared to the method you're using. The trial division method is very slow once past toy size inputs.  You can have each thread/process sieve a different range.  You may also want to look at how primesieve does its partitioning (it is multi-threaded rather than multi-processor, but still worth considering).